# Google App Engine - Issue running python shell commands from Aptana Studio

Tags: python, google-app-engine, aptana

Hi I'm somewhat of a newbie to python and I'm using app engine and Aptana Studio - I need to run some python shell commands so that i can complete the tasks in this Tutorial on how to set up 118 and django. I have got this all working but i don't understand how i run the python commands to compile the dictionarys such as

```
$ PYTHONPATH=/path/to/googleappengine/python/lib/django/ /path/to/googleappengine/python/lib/django/django/bin/make-messages.py -a
```

To be honest - why am i saying that! I dont know where in aptanna studio i run this command -then worse I don't quite understand what exactly i type based on the above command line.

My path to google app engine is

```
D:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\
```

Can anyone help shed some light on how i do this from aptanna / the root of my project??

I'm following this Tutorial:

http://makeyjl.blogspot.com/2009/02/using-djangos-i18n-in-google-app-engine.html

Answer (score 3):

So after quite a while I found another answer to your question, which was mine before too lol...
There is a tutorial on `python` on `Google App Engine` that explains how to set your `python command line interface` up and running in no time, and coming from someone like me, I really mean it in no time.

There are steps in the tutorials where you have, for instance, to add the link in your user variables path on your system properties where your `python` executable file is located.

Here is the link to where I think the answer to your issue lies:

[Void space tutorial on windows command line interface for python CLI programming](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/command_line.shtml)